# PHP: Add key value to the value of an existing key => value array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structured like so:

```
data: [
    {
       "category": "CAT555",
       "products": {
           "productID": 12345,
           "sku": 3333
       },
    },
    {
      "category": "CAT1111",
      "products": {
          "productID: 12441,
          "sku": 9999
      },
   }
]
```

If I have a new product I'd like to add to the CAT555 category? How would I do that?

Currently have this:

```
$key = array_search($categoryID, array_column($categories, 'categoryID'));

 if ($key != false){
    $categories[$key]['products'][] = [
       'productID': '91232',
       'sku': '52433'
    ];
```

But the result ends up looking like this:

```
data: [
    {
       "category": "CAT555",
       "products": 
       "0": {
            "productID": 12345,
            "sku": 3333
            }
       },
       {
           "productID": 12345,
           "sku": 3333
       },
    },
    {
      "category": "CAT1111",
      "products": {
          "productID: 12441,
          "sku": 9999
      },
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with `array_merge` function:

```
$new_product = [
    'productID' => '91232',
    'sku' => '52433'
 ];
$search_key = 'CAT555';
foreach ($categories as $k => &$v) {
    if ($v['category'] == $search_key) {  // if the needed key is found
        (isset($v['products'][0]))? 
            $v['products'].push($new_product) 
            : $v['products'] = array_merge([$v['products']], [$new_product]);
    }
}

print_r($categories);
```

Comment: Thanks! This got me some progress, though if I loop through more than two new products it appears to start overwriting previous iterations.